# Freeing struct elements of a linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, malloc, free

I am trying to free the struct elements of a struct list with a function. This is the problem:

> `error: no member named 'next' in 'struct _list' alist = alist->next;`

```
typedef struct _element element; 


typedef struct _list { /* Separater Wurzelknoten */
    element *first;    /* Anfang/Kopf der Liste */
    int count;         /* Anzahl der Elemente */
} list;

struct _element {
    char title[MAX_STR];
    char author[MAX_STR];
    int year;
    long long isbn;
    element *next;
};
```

My function:

```
void free_list(list *alist) {
    /* HIER implementieren. */
    list *tempPointer;
    while(alist != NULL) {
        tempPointer = alist;
        alist = alist->next;
        free(tempPointer);
    }
}
```

I cant't change the parameters (`list *alist`). So how do I get access to `next`?

Comment: `alist` isn't part of a list in itself, but it contains a member that is the pointer to the head of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is there because `list` doesn't have a `next` pointer, it only contains a pointer to the list. Since `element` has the next pointer you should replace the temporary variable's type with `element` and use that instead:

```
void free_list(list *alist) {
  element* cur = alist->first;
  while (cur != NULL) {
      element* tempPointer = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
      free(tempPointer);
  }
  // if alist was allocated with malloc()
  free(alist);
}
```

Comment: Right. There may also be a requirement to do a `free(alist)` at the end; we don't know.

Comment: @Kaz I'll add that in just in case.